# Importing Picasso to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, picasso

I have just recently made the transition from Eclipse to Android Studio.  I have not had a problem until I tried to add Picasso to dependencies.  I went to Project Structure -> Dependencies -> then clicked the '+' sign and went into Library Dependency.  I scrolled down to Picasso, clicked ok, and clicked apply.  However, whenever I do this it says "Gradle project sync failed.  Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

To double check, I clicked on build.gradle (Module: app), went down to dependencies to see if it is there and this is what my build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
}
```

The error that it is saying is "Failed to find: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2"
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  I have tried to change the picasso compile line to 2.3.+ and several others but nothing works.

Comment: Not Library Dependency, add it in Module dependence.Another one way is you can directly copy and past the `Picasso` library file in libs folder this works, because in gradle file you added the libs jar acess `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Where should I add the libs file?  There is not a default libs file in android studio when starting a new project.

Comment: No,it's available.See the `archon92` answer.he show,how to see your whole android studio project structure.in there you have libs folder, in there to put `Picasso` jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  I ended up copying in the jar file into the libs folder like you were saying.  However, after I did that I went to Project Structure -> Dependencies -> '+' -> File Dependency.  I then clicked on the Picasso Jar file and applied that.  This resolved my issue and I can now use Picasso without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

This link should help you.Follow the steps excatly as its mentioned and youll be up and running in no time.It worked for me.

[Setup and use Picasso in android studio](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149)

Do this:
1)Download the jar file

2)Add `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'` to the build.gradle file in the dependency section.(2.3.3 being the picasso version.This is subject to change as the version progresses)

3)add the jar file to your libs folder.To do this follow these steps:
Click on the android icon in your project tab and in the drop down menu select "project".

Change your project structure from "Android" to "project" as shown in the screenshots.The libs folder will be visible only in the "project" structure

[image: NO Lib]
[image: Project structure]
[image: libs folder]

Once this is done,you can see the libs folder under the apps directory as shown in the screen shot.
Add the picasso library here and right click on it and select "add as library".Select "Ok" in the dialog menu that appears.

Now gradle will sync again and picasso will be ready for use.

Comment: I followed the link and it is somewhat helpful, but I still could not get it to work.  I am having problems importing the jar.  There is no lib folder in the project and I'm not sure exactly where to add the lib folder to add the jar.  If there is any other help you could offer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to post screen shots of where I have gotten, but I cant right now.  I have the Picasso jar file in the exact same libs as you do, it looks the same.  My build.gradle looks the same as how I posted.  However, when I right click on the jar file, there is no option that says "add as library."  I am still getting the error that says "Failed to find: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2" and "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly."  

I apologize for the continued comments, but I'm not sure where else to go from here.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

While the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` knows how to pull in dependencies from local sources (such as jar files or the support library from the local repository), you need to declare other remote repositories by adding a `repositories` section at the top level of your gradle file (i.e., directly below the `apply plugin` line):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i +1 archon92.  good screenshots.  i followed the screenshots to move .jar into libs folder.  then i followed steps in accepted answer, and the errors went away.  (thank you archon92 and Kenneth Streit)